# Concat results by days ranges

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I have an apartment table:

```
Id:            name:
1              apartment1
2              apartment2
3              apartment3
3              apartment4
```

And an availabilities table:

```
Id      apartment_id       availability_date   remaning_number_places
1           1                  01/02/2017                    3
2           1                  02/02/2017                    2
3           1                  03/02/2017                    2
4           1                  04/02/2017                    2
5           2                  01/02/2017                    2
6           2                  03/02/2017                    2
7           2                  04/02/2017                    2
8           3                  12/02/2017                    2
9           3                  03/02/2017                    1
10          3                  04/02/2017                    1
11          4                  12/02/2017                    2
12          4                  02/02/2017                    2
```

I would like to do a search by starting and ending date with a minimum number of places, for example if I search from 01/02/2017 to 04/02/2017 I should have this result:

```
  Apartment_ids    availabilities   starting_date  ending_date nbr_places
      [1]            [1,2,3,4]       01/02/2017      04/02/2017     2
     [2,4]          [5,6,7,12]       01/02/2017      04/02/2017     2
```

The result must be a concatenation of contiguous days corresponding to given dates.

Thank you at advance.

EDIT : Trying to give more details hereunder:
I need an SQL query to look for an apartment availability for a given period.
As a result, if an apartment is available for the whole period I'm expecting to get it. In addition, I also need to get if more than one apartment are required to cover this given period. In that case, I'm expecting a contiguous list of apartments as a result.
Please, can someone help me build this query?

Comment: Would you show us what you have attempted to do for yourself please.

Comment: This is an interesting project, do let us know if you have a question!

Comment: Please ask a question. Specifications for work you require us to do are ignored most of the time

Comment: It's a little unusual to have a table of the days a thing *isn't* booked!

Comment: @Strawberry yea, good point.

Comment: I need an SQL query to look for an apartment availability for a given period. As a result, if an apartment is available for the whole period I'm expecting to get it. In addition, I also need to get if more than one apartment are required to cover this given period. In that case, I'm expecting a contiguous list of apartments as a result. Please, can someone help me build this query?

Comment: I just cannot imagine a situation in the real world where someone would store 'remaining' availabilities.

Comment: Forget the real world and think to it as abstract example ;)

Comment: OK. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Ok , I have read your post but it doesn't answer my question , for your information I'm working on confidential project and I can't make the concrete table ... can you help with the given question ?